# Flutter Firebase Authentication - get Provider id in FirebaseAuthException with createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a user using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)`.

However in the error if a user account already exists for the email address, I would like to know if the provider is Facebook, Google, Email, etc.

Currently it only tells me 'email-already-in-use'.

So from a user point of view, if I don't remember that I have used Google Login before it will be impossible to login or create a new account because the error message doesn't tell me that I already have an account with same email address using Provider Google.

I would like to know how can I get the provider of the email address for which account already exist, to improve the user experience.

Comment: The method you are looking for is `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`. See the questions I linked for more information.

Comment: Yes fetchSignInMethodsForEmail resolved the issue. Thank you so much. @FrankvanPuffelen you were really helpful as always.